# WebSocket IsWebSocketRequest in WebApi Core is False

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket

In my WebApi I have WebSocket with my own middleware.

```
app.Map("/ws", (_app) => _app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketMiddleware>(handler));
```

In Invoke method in my middleware I would like to check if WebSocket IsWebSocketRequest, but always I have false, why?

I'am run WebSocket using http://localhost:6014/ws

Comment: How are you hosting the app?

Comment: For now I'am running WebApi from VS PPM -> Debug -> Start

Comment: so what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just had the same issue.

In my case, I had to add `app.UseWebSockets();` into the function where the web server is configured.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enabled Web Socket Protocol under windows features
2. Add app.UseWebSockets() right before app.UseEndpoints() in startup.cs